# Issue with mondogb-morphia in grails application to store Map correctly in database

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, dictionary, morphia

I'm using the plugin mongodb-morphia (0.7.8) in a grails (2.0.3) application and I experiment an issue with the type Map. 
I want to store in my database a map of type Map but when I put that in my groovy file :

```
class ServiceInfo {

    String name

    Map<String,?> args

    Date dateCreated // autoset by plugin
    Date lastUpdated // autoset by plugin

    static constraints = {
        name nullable:false
    }
}
```

I obtain the following error :

> 2012-04-29 14:39:43,876 [pool-2-thread-3] ERROR MongodbMorphiaGrailsPlugin  - Error processing mongodb domain Artefact > fr.unice.i3s.modalis.yourcast.provider.groovy.ServiceInfo: Unknown type... pretty bad... call for help, wave your hands... yeah!

I tried just to specify Map in my file:

```
Map args
```

In that case I obtain the following simple warning:

> INFO: MapKeyDifferentFromString complained about fr.unice.i3s.modalis.yourcast.provider.groovy.ServiceInfo.args : Maps cannot be keyed by Object (Map); Use a parametrized type that is supported (Map)

and when I try to save an object, the attribute args is simply omitted in the database. 
For information my objects have this kind of representation:

```
def icalReader= new ServiceInfo(name:"IcalReader", args:['uri':DEFAULT_URL, 'path':"fr.unice.i3s.modalis.yourcast.sources.calendar.icalreader/"])
icalReader.save()
```

Finally, if I just say that args is a List:

```
List args
```

And I change my objects to take a List with only one Map, I just have a warning:

> ATTENTION: The multi-valued field 'fr.unice.i3s.modalis.yourcast.provider.groovy.ServiceInfo.args' is a possible heterogenous collection. It cannot be verified. Please declare a valid type to get rid of this warning. null

but everything works fine and I've my map correctly stored in the database:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("4f9be39f0364bf4002cd48ad"), "name" : "IcalReader", "args" : [     {   "path" : "fr.unice.i3s.modalis.yourcast.sources.calendar.icalreader/",  "uri" : "http://localhost:8080/" } ], "dateCreated" : ISODate("2012-04-28T12:33:35.838Z"), "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2012-04-28T12:33:35.838Z") }

So is there something I forget in defining my map? 
My service does work but I don't like hacks like "encapsulate a map in a list to serialize it" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Map, but could you use embedded datamodel instead?

```
class ServiceInfo {
...
@Embedded
MyArgs args
...
}
```

---

```
class MyArgs {
String key
String value
}
```